# Not Supplying Value to Parameter In SP throwing Error- sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a SP as given below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CHKIndex

@count DECIMAL(10,2) ,
@ID INT = NULL, 
@DATE VARCHAR (MAX)

AS

SELECT  DISTINCT
       COL1,
       COL2
FROM
(    
      SELECT COL1,COL2,rn
      FROM TAB1 T1 
      INNER JOIN TAB2 T2 ON T1.SNO = T2.PNO
)t
where t.rn = 1
AND DATE = @DATE
AND t.ID = @ID

GO
```

When i executed like `EXEC CHKIndex 20,71,22082016`

It is working fine when i supplied value for all three parameter,

but 
starts giving error when not supplied any value for date as

> Procedure or function 'uspECP_Competitive_Index' expects parameter '@DATE', which was not supplied.

i am trying to modify in such a way that if user want to see data based on only @count and @ID
they can able to do so.

if i assign default NULL for @date even than not getting any records in the output.

Please suggest.

Comment: It's expecting a `VARCHAR` value, so you need to wrap the value in single quotes.  (e.g.:  `EXEC CHKIndex 20, 71, '22082016'`)

Comment: @Siyual: if i did something like EXEC CHKIndex 20,71,'', even than i am not getting resultset.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way could be to modify your where clause to be:

```
WHERE
    t.rn = 1
AND DATE = ISNULL(@DATE, DATE)
AND t.ID = @ID
```

A couple of other points to note are

1. You are not using the parameter @count
2. It would make much more sense to use the datetime type for your @Date parameter, rather than varchar(max).

Comment: I believe the index won't be used using `ISNULL` .

Comment: Exactly. That's why I said, "quick and dirty" :-)